# Dynamically adding element to Select and setting the selectindex in JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors, jquery-mobile

I've created a dynamic select list box as below

```
for (var i in c) {
            //alert(c[i].IsDefault);
            if(c[i].IsDefault==true){
                //alert('found default');
                $("#AnsType").append("<option value='" + c[i].ID + "'>" + c[i].Code+ "</option>");
                temp = c[i].Code;
            }
            else{
                $("#AnsType").append("<option value='" + c[i].ID + "'>" + c[i].Code+ "</option>");
            }

        }
```

refreshed it

```
$('#AnsType').selectmenu('refresh');
```

I tried all these methods and tried to select teh 2nd element in teh listnone worked for me.

```
$('#AnsType').val(temp.toString());
$('#AnsType').get(3).selectedIndex = 3;
$('select#AnsType').val('3');
$("#AnsType option[text='3']").attr("selected","selected") ;
$("#mydropdownlist").attr('selectedIndex', 1);
$('#AnsType').val(3);
$("#AnsType").attr('selectedIndex', 2);
$("#AnsType").val(c[parseInt(temp)].Code);
$("select#AnsType option[selected]").removeAttr("selected");
$("select#AnsType option[value='"+temp+"']").attr("selected", "selected");
```

this is how when my listbox is created

```
<select id="AnsType" name="AnsType">
        <option value="1">Obokad</option>
        <option value="3">Egen bokning</option>
</select>
```

Any help is appreciated and thanks in advance for your help..

Comment: What do you want to do??

Comment: I want to select the 2nd element in the list.

Comment: Add selected="selected" attribute in the option that you want keep selected.

Comment: `$('#AnsType').get(3).selectedIndex = 3;` - an ID selector should only ever return one single element (because IDs should be unique!), so I'm not sure what you were expecting `get(3)` to return.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want some element to be pre-selected when creating the menu, add the `selected` attribute to the corresponding option element:

```
if(c[i].IsDefault==true){
    $("#AnsType")
        .append("<option value='" + c[i].ID + " selected='selected'">" + c[i].Code+ "</option>");
    temp = c[i].Code;
}
```

Note that you have to refresh again the selectmenu after you programmatically change the value of the underlying select element:

```
$('#AnsType').val('3');
$('#AnsType').selectmenu('refresh');
```

[Documentation](http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.0.1/docs/forms/selects/methods.html)

> **refresh** update the custom select
>   This is used to update the custom select to reflect the native select element's value. If the number of options in the select are different than the number of items in the custom menu, it'll rebuild the custom menu. Also, if you pass a true argument you can force the rebuild to happen